# Xamarin Native Facebook mixed with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, native

I have this Xamarin.Forms project where I am using the Native Facebook sdk in my Droid and iOS projects.

I am having trouble getting to Xamarin forms after logging in in native.

Basically I am launching the Facebook stuff in my main android file.

The problem here is that the FacebookSDK does not seam to work if my class is deriving from FormsApplicationActivity. Therefor I cannot use SetPage. Is there any way I can navigate to my Forms from Native Android?

If I derive from Activity the SDK performs ok, but I get exceptions if deriving from FormsApplicationActivity.

I have tried all kinds of jumping through hoops (like creating a separate FormsApplicationActivity and then getting that to load my App.cs in Forms) but nothing seams to help.

Please help, I have almost no hair left:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is applicable for your specific problem with the Facebook SDK, but

> Is there any way I can navigate to my Forms from Native Android?

is possible!

Actually, when you create a new Xamarin.Forms project that's essentially what's being done for you already. The `.Droid` solution (native Android) starts a container for the `.Forms` solution ( `LoadApplication (new App ());` ).

For you to do this manually, simply make a new Xamarin.Forms solution and remove the followingcode from the `MainActivity.cs`

```
MainLauncher = true
```

Now add a new, regular Android Activity to the `.Droid` project and make sure it's `MainLauncher = true` , making it the starting point of your Android application. From this Activity, you can navigate to any kind of Activity (in your case: the one needed for the Facebook SDK).

When you're done, simply fire up your `MainActivity` containing your Xamarin.Forms solution as you would normally do in Android, for example:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
StartActivityForResult(intent);
```

That would load up the Xamarin.Forms solution as it would normally do. Good luck!